# Getting Stats from A Dialogue Box

Tags: python, http, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

https://classic.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/tampa-bay-rays-vs-ch-white-sox-3386672/ , I'm trying to get data from a pop-up dialog box. Specifically the data in the pop-up window for when you click on (-113, +104). I am using BeautifulSoup and I can't seem to figure out how to get the data from the tables in the pop-up window.

An image of the page.
[image: Here's an image of the page.]

an image of the dialog box when the (-113, +104) box is pressed.
[image: Here's an image of the dialog box when the (-113, +104) box is pressed.]

Do you guys recommend any other web crawler libraries to get the job done? I can't seem to find a way to do this by using BeautifulSoup. Thank you so much for the help!

And sorry for the extremely confusing question. Let me know if you guys need any more clarification.